# How to delete window created by PySide?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

When I created window by `PySide`, then how to delete the window?
I assumed `app.quit` will delete created window. But it doesn't delete the window.

code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = QWidget()
myWindow.show() #create window
app.quit()      #delete window?
```

I'm newbie to `PySide` and GUI programming. This question is upon when I am looking PySide introductory book.

Thanks.

Comment: [close](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close) it

Comment: @SirHacksalot Right thing to do but the questioner should be aware that `close` is just a `hide` and not a `delete` if attribute `QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` is not set. Question was for deletion.

Comment: @Sir Hacksalot: Thanks! `app.close()` worked as my hope!

Answer (score 1):

First, don't forget to call `app.exec_()` to start the main loop.

Now to your question: Call the `.hide()` method, so `myWindow.hide()`. You can make it show again with the `.show()` method.

I think you will find this documentation useful: http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySideDocumentation
And there are other listings like tutorials here: [http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aLanguageBindings%3a%3aPySide)

You may want to look at this tutorial first: http://pythoncentral.org/series/python-pyside-pyqt-tutorial/. It is pretty in-depth and probably covers all you need to get started with PySide and GUI programming in general. Good luck!

Comment: I don't know why I need to call `app.exec_()`, I'll ask it as another question. Anyway Thanks.